# INNER JOIN FETCH do NHibernate não está preenchendo propriedades

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Tenho a seguinte *query* em HQL:

```
select
    photoRating
from
    PhotoRating as photoRating
inner join fetch
    photoRating.FormularioRespostaDoUsuario as form
inner join fetch
    form.Trecho as section
```

E sempre que a executo utilizando o método `ISession.CreateQuery()` a propriedade `Trecho` não é preenchida, fica sempre nula.

Tentei fazer algumas alterações no mapeamento dessa propriedade utilizando `.Fetch.Select()` e `.Fetch.Join()`, mas também não obtive resultado.

Na query acima eu coloquei um INNER JOIN FETCH para a propriedade `FormularioRespostaDoUsuario`, mas mesmo removendo esse INNER JOIN essa propriedade continua sendo preenchida

Eu imagino que o problema possa estar relacionado de alguma maneira com o mapeamento das classes `PhotoRating` e `FormularioRespostaDoUsuario` (tipo da propriedade de mesmo nome na query). Portanto vou postar também o mapeamento dessas duas classes:

```
public class PhotoRatingMap : ClassMap<PhotoRating>
{
    public PhotoRatingMap()
    {
        Table("PhotoRating");
        Id(x => x.Id)
            .GeneratedBy.Native();
        OptimisticLock.Version();
        Map(x => x.CollaboratorId, "Collaborator_Id");
        Map(x => x.Rating);
        Map(x => x.RatingDate);
        References(x => x.FormularioRespostaDoUsuario)
            .Class(typeof(FormularioRespostaDoUsuario))
            .Not.Nullable()
            .Column("Answer_Id")
            .Fetch.Select();
    }
}

public class FormularioRespostaDoUsuarioMap : ClassMap<FormularioRespostaDoUsuario>
{
    public FormularioRespostaDoUsuarioMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
        References(x => x.Formulario).Not.Nullable();
        References(x => x.FormularioPergunta).Not.Nullable();
        References(x => x.FormularioPerguntaResposta).Nullable();
        References(x => x.Colaborador).Not.Nullable();
        References(x => x.Product).Nullable();
        Map(x => x.TextoResposta).Length(255).Nullable();
        Map(x => x.DataDaInclusao).Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.DataDaExclusao).Nullable();
        Map(x => x.Ativo).Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.DentroRange).Not.Nullable();
        References(x => x.Trecho)
            .Nullable()
            .Fetch.Join();
        References(x => x.Pdv).Nullable();
        References(x => x.Coaching).Nullable();
        Map(x => x.DataDaResposta).Nullable();
        Map(x => x.NumeroResposta).Nullable();
        Map ( x => x.Indice ).Nullable();
        Map(x => x.Chave).Nullable();
        Map(x => x.PontuacaoAbsolutaFormularioPergunta).Nullable();
        Map(x => x.PontuacaoFormularioPerguntaResposta).Nullable();
        Map(x => x.PontuacaoRelativaFormularioPergunta).Nullable();
        Map(x => x.PontuacaoCalculada).Nullable();
        HasMany(x => x.PhotoRatings)
            .KeyColumn("Answer_Id")
            .Inverse()
            .Fetch.Select()
            .AsSet();
    }
}
```

Obrigado.